# Express middleware error handler

Tags: node.js, express

Following a generated template for express. In the `app.js` there is a following snippet

```
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Per my understanding, the middleware will run in order from `app.use('/users', users)` to 404 handler to error handler. My question is how will it be possible to reach error handler and execute this line `res.status(err.status || 500);` ? Wont every failed request be passed through 404 handler first and therefor getting the status code of `404`? Please let me know if I am missing something! Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it won't. If you look at these event handlers declarations you'll see that error handler for unhandled error, has an additional `err` parameter:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
```

> Error-handling middleware always takes four arguments. You must provide four arguments to identify it as an error-handling middleware function. Even if you don’t need to use the next object, you must specify it to maintain the signature. Otherwise, the next object will be interpreted as regular middleware and will fail to handle errors. For details about error-handling middleware.

So, when the route is not found, the last declared middleware is calling, it's 404 error handler.

But when you call `next` with error: `next(err)` or your code throws an error, the last error handler is calling.

Answer (score 3):

System error should be handled before `404`

```
app.use('/users', users);

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // No routes handled the request and no system error, that means 404 issue.
  // Forward to next middleware to handle it.
  if (!err) return next();

  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// catch 404. 404 should be consider as a default behavior, not a system error.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);
  res.render('Not Found');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Wont every failed request be passed through 404 handler first and therefor getting the status code of 404?

No, the 404 route is just a standard middleware and usually wired up last, meaning if no other routes handle the request they will eventually hit the 404.

The 500 is a special type of middleware, you'll notice it has 4 parameters (first one being an error param). This middleware is invoked as soon as you call `next` with an error, or any sort of data for that matter.

See [the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something to note for anyone else that stumbles around this post.

Your **last** middleware to be invoked (if none gets invoked) - will be 404, it doesn't take an `err` as its middleware parameter. Hence, you can't/shouldn't try to catch the 404 before any other middleware. So your **last** middleware should be without the `err` parameter like the example below and of course, should be at the bottom of your application stack.

```
//at the botton of your app.js
// catch 404.
//no err parameter
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("404Page"{
        url: req.url
    });
});
```

If you want to catch your errors before it goes to this handler use a `(err, req, res, next)` before this middleware.